# How to get a more dense representation from Counter?

Tags: python

I have a dict of values, which I want to sum up. 
I have used this code to achieve this

```
countTest = Counter(chain.from_iterable(e.items() for e in tickets))
result = [{'name': key, 'value': value} for key, value in countTest.items()]
print(json.dumps(result, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

This produces the following values, which is the values that I expect.

```
[
    {
        "name": [
            "ticket",
            "Class A"
        ],           
        "value": 1
    },
    {
        "name": [
            "ticket",
            "Class B"
        ],
        "value": 2
    },
    {
        "name": [
            "ticket",
            "Class C"
        ],
        "value": 3
    }
]
```

However I would like a more dense representation of this, preferably like this

```
{
    "ticket": {
        “Class A”: 1,
        “Class B”: 2,
        “Class C”: 3
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Construct your `result` correctly then. You get what you wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
In [11]: lst = [{'name': ['ticket', 'Class A'], 'value': 1},
...:  {'name': ['ticket', 'Class B'], 'value': 2},
...:  {'name': ['ticket', 'Class C'], 'value': 3}]

In [12]: {'tickets':dict((i['name'][1],i['value']) for i in lst)}
Out[12]: {'tickets': {'Class A': 1, 'Class B': 2, 'Class C': 3}}
```

Where `lst` is the first result that you generated.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

`itertools` harder.

```
>>> {name: {item['name'][1]: item['value'] for item in items} for name, items in itertools.groupby(result, lambda x: x['name'][0])}
{'ticket': {'Class A': 1, 'Class B': 2, 'Class C': 3}}
```

From there the JSON is easy.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with your original `result` and assuming that "ticket" is the only attribute:

```
print(json.dumps({'ticket' : {x['name'][1] : x['value'] for x in result}}, 
                  sort_keys=True, indent=4))
#{
#    "ticket": {
#        "Class A": 1,
#        "Class B": 2,
#        "Class C": 3
#    }
#}
```